# Why do the subsequent elements overlap when using the same number z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I wrote the following source code.

In this HTML and CSS, `.box2` is displayed above`.box3` when hovering to `.box3`.

But this was different from my expectation.

This code expect that `box1` and`box2` will generate the same stack level stack context and `box3` with`position: fixed` will be displayed above the other elements It was.

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  background: #ffa;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  background: #faf;
  position: relative;
}

.box3,
.box4 {
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
}

.box1:hover .box3,
.box2:hover .box4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box4:hover,
.box3:hover {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #aff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

To realize the behavior I expected, I have to set `z-index: 1;` in `box 3`. To make it my predicted behavior.

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  background: #ffa;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  background: #faf;
  position: relative;
}

.box3,
.box4 {
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
}

.box3 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.box1:hover .box3,
.box2:hover .box4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box4:hover,
.box3:hover {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #aff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

What kind of force is acting on each element, is it occurring?

I read the W3C article that I searched for and hit, and the introduction article of `z-index`, but I could not understand this problem.

Comment: Do you need the relative positioning of the parent boxes?

Comment: Yes, I expect that stacking context will be generated by giving `position: relative` to parent boxes(` box1, box2`).

Answer (score 1):

As you note, `.box1` and `.box2` are participating in the same stacking context (the root stacking context), with a z-index of auto. This causes them to be painted in source order with a stack level of 0.

However, because their z-index is auto, they do not establish their own stacking contexts for `.box3` and `.box4` respectively. This means that *all four elements* are participating in the same, root stacking context with a stack level of 0. As a result, `.box2` will always be painted over `.box1` *and* its descendants (in this case, `.box3`) simply because `.box2` comes after `.box1` in source order. This is true even though `.box3` and `.box4` are fixed positioned and therefore do establish their own stacking contexts. See [section 9.9 of CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) (emphasis mine):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. **the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.**
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Setting the z-index of `.box3` to 1 ensures that it's painted above all the other boxes, whose stack level remains 0.